# Verification of Google ID token in Java

Tags: java, google-oauth, access-token, webresource

I am using the below code for verifying the google id token. It always giving me the below error. But with the same headers i am able to do the verification in POST MAN tool. Please help me to resolve this.

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    WebResource service = 
    client.resource("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo");



    try {
        ClientResponse response = service.header("Authorization",
    "Bearer ya29.Glt6BGkbIzLEjeeQ5Q8O51Jh7-PFD3hVLM7PORixSTVFY-
    iduKE8HmK8KMtzYz-
    yJ9rUqo_xY9yVKl5b6CAiTNAtFErb0bZJB3vX6vPZVRPwbY6kVCIDbukDc9FA")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .header("Accept", 
    "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
    application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8").get(ClientResponse.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>           com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET 
>           https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo returned a response status 
>           of 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Are you using the google apis java client library?   I would think it would have a method for validation.   That doesnt look like the corect end point for validing the token id